# OpenJRE instead of Oracle JRE

Tags: java, openjdk

Is there an equivalent openJRE like [openJDK](https://jdk.java.net/11/)?

I would like to use openJRE if possible to enable java in Internet Explorer instead of Using Oracle Java

Is it possible to Enable Java Applet in Internet Explorer using OpenJDK?
if yes How?

Answer (score 1):

First go here:

https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html

Then under Platform, choose `Windows x64 jre`. Then just below that, it will
give you a link similar to this:

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.11%2B9/OpenJDK11U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.11_9.zip

Answer (score 1):

Now that AdoptOpenJDK has been moved into Eclipse Temurian, the link for downloading the JRE is https://adoptium.net/en-GB/marketplace . Still choose Windows, x64, jre, and the appropriate version.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1140199)

Answer (score -1):

Open Control Panel > Java and you should be able to Add a new Java.
Select OpenJDK Java.
Having said that I haven't tried running OpenJDK java with IE and launching sites/apps that use it. Here is the screen shot of the settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yynUe.png)

Comment: i don't see any javacpl (java control panel) under jdk-11.0.2\bin you are giving instructions for Oracle Java